# "Slip up" usage

Tags: verbs, headlinese

> 1. December home sales slip; up 12.8% in 2012
> 2. December home sales slip up 12.8% in 2012
> 3. December home sales slip up; up 12.8% in 2012
> 4. December home sales slip up up 12.8% in 2012

1 is the original usatoday.com headline, but I have doubts on "slip up" usage. So, the question is: What is the difference between 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: Sorry Carlo, but this is another case of "headline grammar" - which isn't subject to normal rules, so it's Too Localised. But for the record, 2/3/4 are all gibberish. The *original* makes sense (note the semicolon). It's really two sentences that are actually somewhat contradictory. Sales slipped by 1% in December, even though they were up by 12.8% averaged over the entire year. There is no syntactic connection between ***slip*** and ***up***.

Comment: It would've been a better headline had it read "December home sales slip {**though** / **, but**} up 12.8% in 2012". There probably wasn't enough space for the extra characters, so a semicolon was the next best choice. I disagree that this is too localized for a Q on ELL. FumbleFingers' explanation actually teaches EFL students how to read & better understand all headlines because it explains the meaning & implies that there's an **abnormal rule the reader must be aware of**. [Jolly good](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/jolly-good), FF!

Comment: **Leave Open.**  I disagree that headlinese is too localized by definition.  I think the weird grammar in headlines is both [possible to describe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese#Syntax) and useful to English Language Learners.  The community could decide it's *off topic*, but I don't believe it has done so.

Comment: To expand slightly on FumbleFingers' comment: *slip*, in this context, means roughly "decrease".

Comment: @snailplane: I think it's seriously stretching language to say there's a "grammar" involved here. Besides which, this example is so unusual it would be Too Localised regardless. You wouldn't normally get two such superficially contradictory "sentences" in "headlinese" (and even when you get compatible elements, they're not normally separated by a semicolon). Which in this case makes the headline somewhat opaque even to native speakers accustomed to reading "financialese". I stand by my closevote - it's not a useful question here on ELL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the original headline, "slip up" isn't actually used (only "slip"). Here, "slip" means "decrease" or "fall," e.g., "the stock price slipped to $50" or "gas prices have slipped to $3.24."

> December home sales slip; up 12.8% in 2012

This headline makes sense. Formally, the second clause should be a complete sentence because it comes after a semicolon, so the author intended for this to be understood as something like "December home sales slip; *they [the home sales] were* up 12.8% in 2012."

> December home sales slip up 12.8% in 2012

This one doesn't make as much sense. "Slip up" is not something I hear a lot, but when I do it's usually as a noun meaning "mistake" (most likely hyphenated): "Karyn's slip-up cost the company five thousand dollars in printing costs." As a verb, though, this makes very little sense.

> December home sales slip up; up 12.8% in 2012

This one might make a little more sense if "slip up" as a verb means "to make a mistake." Then it's something like "December home sales slip up *[they made a mistake]*; *they were* up 12.8% in 2012." But that's a very awkward phrase, because *sales* aren't usually viewed as things that can make mistakes.

> December home sales slip up up 12.8% in 2012

This one really doesn't make any sense, even if we try to use "slip up" as a verb.

I hope this helps!